# Checking whether a string starts with XXXX

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I would like to know how to check whether a string starts with "hello" in Python.

In Bash I usually do:

```
if [[ "$string" =~ ^hello ]]; then
 do something here
fi
```

How do I achieve the same in Python?

Answer (score 838, accepted):

```
aString = "hello world"
aString.startswith("hello")
```

More info about [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=startswith#str.startswith).

Answer (score 137):

[RanRag has already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8802889/1138689) it for your specific question.

However, more generally, what you are doing with

```
if [[ "$string" =~ ^hello ]]
```

is a *regex* match. To do the same in Python, you would do:

```
import re
if re.match(r'^hello', somestring):
    # do stuff
```

Obviously, in this case, `somestring.startswith('hello')` is better.

Comment: Just wanted to add that for what I was doing, re.match and re.sub  was always significantly slower than any other method.

Answer (score 63):

In case you want to match *multiple* words to your magic word, you can pass the words to match as a tuple:

```
>>> magicWord = 'zzzTest'
>>> magicWord.startswith(('zzz', 'yyy', 'rrr'))
True
```

[`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) takes a string or a tuple of strings.

Answer (score 33):

Can also be done this way..

```
regex=re.compile('^hello')

## THIS WAY YOU CAN CHECK FOR MULTIPLE STRINGS
## LIKE
## regex=re.compile('^hello|^john|^world')

if re.match(regex, somestring):
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 12):

I did a little experiment to see which of these methods

- `string.startswith('hello')`
- `string.rfind('hello') == 0`
- `string.rpartition('hello')[0] == ''`
- `string.rindex('hello') == 0`

are most efficient to return whether a certain string begins with another string.

Here is the result of one of the many test runs I've made, where each list is ordered to show the least time it took *(in seconds)* to parse 5 million of each of the above expressions during each iteration of the `while` loop I used:

```
['startswith: 1.37', 'rpartition: 1.38', 'rfind: 1.62', 'rindex: 1.62']
['startswith: 1.28', 'rpartition: 1.44', 'rindex: 1.67', 'rfind: 1.68']
['startswith: 1.29', 'rpartition: 1.42', 'rindex: 1.63', 'rfind: 1.64']
['startswith: 1.28', 'rpartition: 1.43', 'rindex: 1.61', 'rfind: 1.62']
['rpartition: 1.48', 'startswith: 1.48', 'rfind: 1.62', 'rindex: 1.67']
['startswith: 1.34', 'rpartition: 1.43', 'rfind: 1.64', 'rindex: 1.64']
['startswith: 1.36', 'rpartition: 1.44', 'rindex: 1.61', 'rfind: 1.63']
['startswith: 1.29', 'rpartition: 1.37', 'rindex: 1.64', 'rfind: 1.67']
['startswith: 1.34', 'rpartition: 1.44', 'rfind: 1.66', 'rindex: 1.68']
['startswith: 1.44', 'rpartition: 1.41', 'rindex: 1.61', 'rfind: 2.24']
['startswith: 1.34', 'rpartition: 1.45', 'rindex: 1.62', 'rfind: 1.67']
['startswith: 1.34', 'rpartition: 1.38', 'rindex: 1.67', 'rfind: 1.74']
['rpartition: 1.37', 'startswith: 1.38', 'rfind: 1.61', 'rindex: 1.64']
['startswith: 1.32', 'rpartition: 1.39', 'rfind: 1.64', 'rindex: 1.61']
['rpartition: 1.35', 'startswith: 1.36', 'rfind: 1.63', 'rindex: 1.67']
['startswith: 1.29', 'rpartition: 1.36', 'rfind: 1.65', 'rindex: 1.84']
['startswith: 1.41', 'rpartition: 1.44', 'rfind: 1.63', 'rindex: 1.71']
['startswith: 1.34', 'rpartition: 1.46', 'rindex: 1.66', 'rfind: 1.74']
['startswith: 1.32', 'rpartition: 1.46', 'rfind: 1.64', 'rindex: 1.74']
['startswith: 1.38', 'rpartition: 1.48', 'rfind: 1.68', 'rindex: 1.68']
['startswith: 1.35', 'rpartition: 1.42', 'rfind: 1.63', 'rindex: 1.68']
['startswith: 1.32', 'rpartition: 1.46', 'rfind: 1.65', 'rindex: 1.75']
['startswith: 1.37', 'rpartition: 1.46', 'rfind: 1.74', 'rindex: 1.75']
['startswith: 1.31', 'rpartition: 1.48', 'rfind: 1.67', 'rindex: 1.74']
['startswith: 1.44', 'rpartition: 1.46', 'rindex: 1.69', 'rfind: 1.74']
['startswith: 1.44', 'rpartition: 1.42', 'rfind: 1.65', 'rindex: 1.65']
['startswith: 1.36', 'rpartition: 1.44', 'rfind: 1.64', 'rindex: 1.74']
['startswith: 1.34', 'rpartition: 1.46', 'rfind: 1.61', 'rindex: 1.74']
['startswith: 1.35', 'rpartition: 1.56', 'rfind: 1.68', 'rindex: 1.69']
['startswith: 1.32', 'rpartition: 1.48', 'rindex: 1.64', 'rfind: 1.65']
['startswith: 1.28', 'rpartition: 1.43', 'rfind: 1.59', 'rindex: 1.66']
```

I believe that it is pretty obvious from the start that the `startswith` method would come out the most efficient, as returning whether a string begins with the specified string is its main purpose.

What surprises me is that the seemingly impractical `string.rpartition('hello')[0] == ''` method always finds a way to be listed first, before the `string.startswith('hello')` method, every now and then. The results show that using `str.partition` to determine if a string starts with another string is more efficient then using both `rfind` and `rindex`.

Another thing I've noticed is that `string.rfind('hello') == 0` and `string.rindex('hello') == 0` have a good battle going on, each rising from fourth to third place, and dropping from third to fourth place, which makes sense, as their main purposes are the same.

Here is the code:

```
from time import perf_counter

string = 'hello world'
places = dict()

while True:
    start = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(5000000):
        string.startswith('hello')
    end = perf_counter()
    places['startswith'] = round(end - start, 2)

    start = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(5000000):
        string.rfind('hello') == 0
    end = perf_counter()
    places['rfind'] = round(end - start, 2)

    start = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(5000000):
        string.rpartition('hello')[0] == ''
    end = perf_counter()
    places['rpartition'] = round(end - start, 2)

    start = perf_counter()
    for _ in range(5000000):
        string.rindex('hello') == 0
    end = perf_counter()
    places['rindex'] = round(end - start, 2)
    
    print([f'{b}: {str(a).ljust(4, "4")}' for a, b in sorted(i[::-1] for i in places.items())])
```

Answer (score 0):

strings behave like lists in Python so you could do:

> astring = "hello world"
> astring[:5] == 'hello'