# Python - checking if a string starts with "Yes" or "No"?

Tags: python

I want to make a function which checks whether a string starts with "Yes" or "No" but I'm not sure how.

```
If string begins with "Yes"
return "Yes"
```

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Comment: Why I downvoted the question: because you did not show the most basic effort for resolving the problem yourself.

Comment: does `Yesterday` count?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking whether a string starts with XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802860/checking-whether-a-string-starts-with-xxxx)

Answer (score 14):

Try [startswith function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
if myStr.startswith("Yes"):
    return "Yes"
elif myStr.startswith("No"):
    return "No"
```

Note that there is also [endswith function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) to check that your string is ending with the text expected.

If you need to check that string is not starts with:

```
if not myStr.lower().startswith("yes"):
    return "Not Yes"
elif not myStr.lower().startswith("no"):
    return "Not No"
```

Comment: do you know how to check if a string does not start with "Yes"?

Comment: @user2278906 please please read this: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: @user2278906 check the updated answer, the idea is that startswith itself returns you a boolean value on whether strings starting(True) with the specified parameter or not(False), So all that you need is to put 'not' and this will revert logic

Answer (score 6):

Possibly more flexible is good

```
if s.lower().startswith("yes"):
    return "Yes"
elif s.lower().startswith("no"):
    return "No"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
yourString.startsWith("Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
String.startswith("yes")
```

if the string doesn't start with yes it will return false and if it does, true.

Answer (score 0):

name = "Yes? test"

if name.index('Yes') == 0:

```
print 'String find!!'
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be the best solution:

```
def yesOrNo(j):  
  if j[0].lower() == 'y':
    return True
  elif j[0].lower() == 'n':
    return False
  else:
    return None
def untilYN():
  yn = input('Yes or no: ')
  j = yesOrNo(yn)
  while j == None:
    yn = input('Please insert yes or no again; there may have been an error: ')
    j = yesOrNo(yn)
  return j
print(untilYN())
```

For example:

```
print(untilYN())
>> Yes or no: Maybe
>> Please insert yes or no again; there may have been an error: yeah then
True
```