# In Python 3, how do I determine if a prefix is in a string?

Tags: string, python-3.x, recursion, boolean

I need to recursively write a function that determines if a prefix, for example 'f', is the prefix of a string. If it is the prefix, it needs to return True, and if it is not the prefix, it needs to return False. How do I do this?

Comment: any attempts any ex?

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: Heard of [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking whether a string starts with XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802860/checking-whether-a-string-starts-with-xxxx)

Answer (score 8):

Use the `startswith()` method :

```py
if string.startswith(prefix):
    # do something
```