# How can I know if a string starts with a string from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if a given strings starts with some strings from a list.

```
p1 = ["I2101", "I222", "I7102", "I252"]
g1 = ["I21", "I22", "I252"]
g2 = ["I71"]
for p in p1:
    if p in g1:
        print("grupo1")
    elif p in g2:
        print("grupo2")
```

It should show grupo1 , grupo1, grupo2, grupo1 but It only works with I252 because it's the same as g1[2]

Comment: I'm sure that you can find existing advice for checking whether a string has a specific prefix using Python :) For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982953/in-python-3-how-do-i-determine-if-a-prefix-is-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

```
p1 = ["I2101", "I222", "I7102", "I252"]

g1 = ["I21", "I22", "I252"]
g2 = ["I71"]

for p in p1:
    if any(p.startswith(g) for g in g1):
        print('{}: Grupo 1'.format(p))
    elif any(p.startswith(g) for g in g2):
        print('{}: Grupo 2'.format(p))
```

Prints:

```
I2101: Grupo 1
I222: Grupo 1
I7102: Grupo 2
I252: Grupo 1
```

Edit (alternative version):

```
g = [(k, 'Grupo 1') for k in g1] + [(k, 'Grupo 2') for k in g2]
print([v[1] for p in p1 for v in g if p.startswith(v[0])])
```

Prints:

```
['Grupo 1', 'Grupo 1', 'Grupo 2', 'Grupo 1']
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner Corrected.