# How to append to a list while code is iterating and save the list (For twitch chat bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, twitch

I'm creating a chat bot for twitch, more importantly, I'm attempting to have a list that can be added to during iteration and can also be accessed to from within the channel chat. This is the overall code:
https://pastebin.com/maCbceaB
I'm focused on this portion of the code however:

```
clist = ["!add", ]
        if message.strip() == "!add":
            chat(s, "Syntax: !add !<command> <what the command does>")
        if message.strip().startswith("!add"):
            clist.append(message[5:])
            chat(s, "The command has been added!")
```

EDIT: I'm moreso focused on how to add to the list while the code is iterating because I have to be able to add to the `clist` because it will be used in:

```
if message.strip() == "!commands":
            chat(s, clist)
```

Currently this code will only output: `['!add']` when `!commands` is used
All the options I've researched are typically for massive lists and mine will be consisted mostly of strings so I need something fairly simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking whether a string starts with XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802860/checking-whether-a-string-starts-with-xxxx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a string starts with a substring you can use the String `startswith` method:

```
if message.startswith('!add'):
```

and then you can grab the command by removing the '!add ' part using a String slice:

```
message[5:]
```

Your code will be as follows:

```
>>> clist = []
>>> message = '!add testcommand'
>>> if message.startswith('!add'):
>>>     clist.append(message[5:])
>>> clist
>>> ['testcommand']
```

Comment: I would suggest using `message[5:]`, rather than `message.replace('!add ', '')`. It may lose some clarity, but will also not lead to any unexpected results if `!add` appears later in the string, and is probably a little faster as it's more specified, and is more concise.

Comment: Replacing the substring means `'!add '` can't be part of your list. You could use `message[len('!add '):]` instead to capture everything after the first `'!add '`

Comment: The add command would have to be a hardcoded value anyways, because you couldnt add it to the clist by doing '!add !add'..