# What python code allows me to print out elements from a list that starts with a letter?

Tags: python

Example:
I created a  list named months of the months of the year. How do I write a for loop that iterates over the elements of months and prints out each one that begins with letter ‘J’, one month per line.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802860/checking-whether-a-string-starts-with-xxxx

Answer (score 1):

In python you can iterate over a list using a for loop. You can then have a conditional statement that checks if the month begins with 'J'. Example:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March' 'June', 'October']
for month in months:
    if month[0] == 'J':
        print(month)
```

This results in

```
January
June
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.startswith()`

```
[print(i) for i in months if (i.lower()).startswith('j')]
```

Or

```
months = ['January', 'July', 'Nov']
for i in months:
    i = i.lower()
    if (i.lower()).startswith('j'):
        print(i)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 example.py 
> January
> July
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to filter elements out based on their initial letter this should help: [Checking whether a string starts with XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802860/checking-whether-a-string-starts-with-xxxx)

```
months=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
for m in months:
    if m.startswith('J'):
        print m

January
June
July
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each element and see if its a string. If it is, then check the first element.

```
yourList = ["January"]
checkLetter = "J"
for element in yourList:
    if isinstance(element,str):
        if element[0]== checkLetter:
            print(element)
```