# Wildcard list matching in python

Tags: python

I have a list of strings

```
l = [
   '/api/users/*',
   '/api/account/*
]
```

And paths are like

```
/api/users/add/
/api/users/edit/1
/api/users/
/api/account/view/1
/api/account/
```

How can I perform filter for the paths if they exist in the list `l`.

condition like

```
'/api/users/add/' in l
```

should return `True` and for all given paths above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you've written to solve this problem.

Comment: If the wildcards are always at the end of a path, you don't need wildcard matching and you can just use prefix match. If you do need wildcard matching, use the appropriate library (`fnmatch`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your wildcards are always the last thing in the query string, I recommend chopping it off and using [`.startswith()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8802860/699305). Otherwise, use the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) module which interprets "glob"-style wildcards:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch

def listglob(path, patterns):
    return any(fnmatch(path, pat) for pat in patterns)

for path in paths:
    print(path, listglob(path, l))
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to see if the wildcard pattern would hold true. For this you can use the `fnmatch` module from `glob`. Supposing you have this:

```
l = [
   '/api/users/*',
   '/api/account/*'
]

paths = [
   '/api/users/add/'
   '/api/users/edit/1',
   '/api/users/',
   '/api/account/view/1',
   '/api/account/',
   '/non/existent/path'
]
```

You could get this:

```
>>> import fnmatch
>>> [any(fnmatch.fnmatch(path, pat) for pat in l) for path in paths]
[True, True, True, True, False]
```

Comment: `fnmatch` is its own module, `glob` just uses it.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [
   '/api/users/*',
   '/api/account/'
]

paths = [
'/api/users/add/'
'/api/users/edit/1',
'/api/users/',
'/api/account/view/1',
'/api/account/'
]

for path in paths:
    if path in l:
        print("Path: {}, found in the list".format(path))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Path: /api/account/, found in the list
```

**EDIT:**

If you want a method that would return the boolean value:

```
l = [
   '/api/users/*',
   '/api/account/'
]

paths = [
'/api/users/add/',
'/api/users/edit/1',
'/api/users/',
'/api/account/view/1',
'/api/account/'
]

def checkPath(path):
        if path in l:
            return True
        else:
            return False

for i in range(0,len(paths)):
    print(checkPath(paths[i]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
False
False
False
False
True
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you want the `*` ones to match with the path, you can remove the `*` from the original list and then iterate like:

```
def checkPath(path):
        if path in l_new:
            return True
        else:
            return False

# strip the asterick
l_new = [s.strip('*') for s in l]

for i in range(0,len(paths)):
    print(checkPath(paths[i]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
False
False
True
False
True
```

Comment: What if there are paths in `l` that don't have a `*`, i.e. require a perfect match?

Comment: @tobias_k The first Edit would work in that case, if you remove `*` from the `l` it would return `False
False
True
False
True`

Comment: But if you just remove the `*` how can you differentiate between paths that allow for a suffix and those that don't?

Comment: Ah, in that case, I think the best shot would be `fnmatch` as described already!

Answer (score 1):

The `fnmatch` solutions posted already are certainly recommended for this problem, however, the answer below demonstrates a non-import solution:

```
def matchs_path(_pattern, _input):
  _a, _b = filter(None, _pattern.split('/')), filter(None, _input.split('/'))
  while True:
    _val, _val2 = next(_a, None), next(_b, None)
    if _val is None and _val2 is None:
      return True
    if _val != '*' and _val != _val2:
      return False
    if _val == "*":
      _to_see = next(_a, None)
      if _to_see is None:
        return True
      while True:
        c = next(_b, None)
        if c is None:
          return True
        if c == _to_see:
          break
```

---

```
patterns = ['/api/users/*', '/api/account/*', '/new/*/test/here']
data = ['/api/users/add/', '/api/users/edit/1', '/api/users/', '/api/account/view/1', '/api/account/', '/going/to/fail/here', '/new/additional/abc/test/here']
new_results = {i:{c:matchs_path(i, c) for c in data} for i in patterns}
```

Output:

```
{
 "/api/users/*": {
    "/api/users/add/": true,
    "/api/users/edit/1": true,
    "/api/users/": true,
    "/api/account/view/1": false,
    "/api/account/": false,
    "/going/to/fail/here": false,
    "/new/additional/abc/test/here": false
 },
  "/api/account/*": {
    "/api/users/add/": false,
    "/api/users/edit/1": false,
    "/api/users/": false,
    "/api/account/view/1": true,
    "/api/account/": true,
    "/going/to/fail/here": false,
    "/new/additional/abc/test/here": false
 },
 "/new/*/test/here": {
    "/api/users/add/": false,
    "/api/users/edit/1": false,
    "/api/users/": false,
    "/api/account/view/1": false,
    "/api/account/": false,
    "/going/to/fail/here": false,
    "/new/additional/abc/test/here": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to replace a `*` at the end of the path pattern with `.*` and than use those as regular expressions themselves to match the paths in the list.

```
paths = ['/api/users/add/',
         '/api/users/edit/1',
         '/api/users/',
         '/api/account/view/1',
         '/api/account/',
         '/not/a/valid/path']
l = ['/api/users/*', '/api/account/*']
patterns = [re.compile(re.sub("\*$", ".*", s)) for s in l]

>>> [path for path in paths if any(p.match(path) for p in patterns)]
['/api/users/add/',
 '/api/users/edit/1',
 '/api/users/',
 '/api/account/view/1',
 '/api/account/']
```

Comment: Or you could use `fnmatch.translate` to convert all wildcard symbols for you. But why bother, when Python also has support for the glob syntax?