# How do I use the if statement for input starting with a certain letter

Tags: python

I am trying to print a certain output if the user's input (`greet`) begins with a certain word "hello" else if the input begins with h using the `if` statement.

I have tried:

```py
if greet == "hello":
    print("wrong") 
elif greet == "h_" #(but not hello)
    print(" okay")
else: 
    print("good")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking whether a string starts with XXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802860/checking-whether-a-string-starts-with-xxxx)

Comment: @gimix `greet == "h_"` does not check if `greet` starts with `"h"`.

Comment: That's for sure :D I only suggested to OP that they first of all polish their code, since in its initial form it was not even Python correct code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `.startswith()`:

```
if greet.startswith("hello"):
    print("wrong")
elif greet.startswith("h"):
    print("okay")
else:
    print("good")
```

Comment: This is the best answer towards what OP asked. My answer had all kinds of checks for lower/upper, if nothing was entered, and if a space was the first entered character.....but OP didn't ask for any of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It ignores leading and trailing spaces by calling `strip`, it has a conditional for if nothing was placed in the input, and lastly it's case insensitive because it standardizes the input to `lower`:

```py
greet = input().strip()

if len(greet) > 0:
    firstWord = greet.split(" ")[0].lower()
    if firstWord == 'hello':
        print("wrong")
    elif firstWord[0] == "h":
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("good")
else:
    print("You must enter something")
```